# how to pass variable in url to python flask

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

I am using angularjs to pass the data to back end(python flask)

```
var currenttopic = "All";
    $http.post("/CA/"currenttopic,date).success(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
```

and in backend the python flask code is something like

```
@app.route('/CA/<topic>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def competitivepertopic(topic):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(topic)
        data = request.get_json()
        pass
    return json.dumps({'data': topic})
```

now how can i pass currenttopic variable to backend?

Comment: that is a different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$http.post("/CA/" + currenttopic, date).success(function(response) {
```

or with ES6:

```
$http.post(`/CA/${currenttopic}`, date).success(function(response) {
```

Comment: is that a tilde symbol?

Comment: the first line worked for me. thanks for the help